# how to validate input with "real" as the variable to numbers only?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

im a coding newbie, currently using freepascal to learn. i want to make a simple temperature converter. im struggling at how to validate the input. because im using "real" as var, and i cant validate the input to numbers and negative sign only. i want to write "false input" and repeat to temperature input, if the input contains alphabet/alphanumeric. but when i input the temperature in alphabet/alphanumeric it will just exiting from program. how to do this correctly? is there any solution?

input validation with "real" as the variable

here's my current code

```
program Fahrenheit_to_Celsius;
uses crt;
function strtofloat (floatstring : string) : extended;
var F: string;
floatvalue: extended;
C: real;
exit: boolean;
decision: shortstring;
    begin
     clrscr;
     textattr :=$3;
     gotoxy (52,1);
     writeln ('Fahrenheit to Celsius Converter');
      repeat
       write ('Input Fahrenheit: ');
       readln (F);
       begin
        try
        F := strtofloat ('10 E 2');
        except
        on exception : econverterror do
        showmessage (exception.message);
        end;
        try
        F := strtofloat ('$FF');
        except
        on exception : econverterror do
        showmessage (exception.message);
        end;
       C := ((F-32)*(5/9));
       writeln ('Temperature in Celsius: ', C:0:5);
        begin
         writeln;
         gotoxy ((wherex () + 56), (wherey() - 0));
         writeln ('Convert again or exit?');
         gotoxy ((wherex () + 31), (wherey() - 0));
         writeln ('Input e then press enter to exit or input anything else to convert again');
         write ('Decision:');
         readln (decision);
         if (decision = 'e') then
         exit := true
         else
         exit := false;
         gotoxy ((wherex () + 0), (wherey() - 3));
         delline;
         gotoxy ((wherex () + 0), (wherey() - 0));
         delline;
        end;
      until exit;
    end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I practiced pascal but I will give you an idea, I think you cannot validate it this way because if you declare the input as `real` once the program recive an non valid `input` it exits, so what I suggest, is to declare the variable as `string` instead, then you create a function to validate it, finally if the function returns `true` you convert the `string` to `float`.

The function should loop through every character in the recieved `string` and returns `false` if

1. one character is not a number or not a `.`
2. the string contains more then one `.` ( create a variable and increment it every time you catch a character equal to `.` )
3. the first character is `.`
4. the last character is `.`

Comment: No, don't code this yourself. Call the library function TryStrToFloat.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The questioner declares to be a coding novice. I think it’s a legitimate exercise to do this manually since it’s quite “tangible”. Nevertheless I agree with you that in a _production_ `program` you’ll use [`sysUtils.tryStrToFloat`](https://WWW.FreePascal.Org/docs-html/current/rtl/sysutils/trystrtofloat.html) instead.

Comment: people usually use pascal to learn programming and especially loops, personally, I never used a library when I programmed with pascal and that's why I didn't give him the code but some tips to do it on his own

Comment: @ahmed how do you read the input without a library? Also, having read the string in and validated it, how do you convert it to a float type in order to do the arithmetic? Remember that you don't use libraries.

Comment: I am not talking about basic libraries

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `readStr('+123.456E-78', x)` is essentially equal to `x := +123.456E-78`. The `readStr` procedure is part of the language as standardized by ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal”.

Comment: @kai that would be one way, but better to do validation and conversion together with TryStrToFloat. And in any case my question was rhetorical. The answerer isn't proposing to convert str to float in their own hand rolled code.

Comment: @ahmed SysUtils is a basic library, isn't it? Given the first sentence of your answer, why not heed the experience of people that have up to date experience.

Comment: So the first thing i must do is change the declaration(variable F from real to integer). And then add the other declaration (create function to validate integer) if function true, use strtofloat and if false make a loop to Fahrenheit input again. So, this strtofloat is necessary because we cant to arithmetic with the string eh?